# Opposite of jQuery.camelCase for CSS property names

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, camelcasing

`jQuery.camelCase` is used to convert dashed CSS properties to camelcased CSSOM(? or DOM?) properties.

I'd like to do the opposite to dynamically create a CSS transition value.

I don't want to use the `all` keyword for this. I'd like to make it possible to not force the coder to only use `background-color` instead of `backgroundColor`.

Is this possible (maybe via jQuery) or will it take lots of code for cross browser support?

**Edit:**

```
$("#example").css("transition-property", "backgroundColor") // Fail
```

I don't want to do exactly the same as in my example but this shows the problem.

I'm trying to iterate through an object that contains css properties and values to set the objects keys as transition-properties. E.g. `{ backgroundColor: "red" }` should set `background-color` as `transition-property` instead of `backgroundColor`.

Comment: But jQuery accepts both, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't need this for the property name itself. I need it to set the `transition` value, e.g. `transition: backgroundColor 1s` will fail. Or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple function to do the job is:

```
function deCase(s) {
    return s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(a) {return '-' + a.toLowerCase()});
}

alert(deCase('scrollbarDarkShadowColor')); // scrollbar-dark-shadow-color
```

There are likely many other ways.

Also, you can do camelCase using:

```
function camelCase(s) {
    return s.replace(/-(.)/g, function(a, $1){return $1.toUpperCase();});
}
```

Comment: https://jsperf.com/uncamel-versus-decase   +1 for being faster than uncamel (in answer below) in current chrome version. no significant difference in firefox/edge.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution from [jQuery.transit.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/source/):

```
function uncamel(str) {
    return str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(letter) { return '-' + letter.toLowerCase(); });
}
```

Any better (more documented/tested) solutions are welcome!